# Is a single partition in an Azure Storage Table a good design?

Tags: azure

I have a system that needs to process ~150 jobs per day.
Additionally, I need to query past jobs efficiently, usually by time-range, but sometimes by other properties like job owner or resource used.

I know that running queries across table partitions can slow down my application, but what if I just put every row into one partition?  If I use datetime.ticks as my rowkey and my query ranges are always small, will this scale well?

I tried putting data into separate partitions by time, but it seems like my queries get slower  as more partitions are included in the query.

Answer (score 1):

The partition is a scale unit. Each partition can receive up to 2000tps before you start receiving throttling errors. As such, as long as you don't forsee exceeding that volume, you should be find fine keeping a single partition.

However, as the size of the partition grows, so will query times. So you may want to factor that in as well.

Comment: Will query times grow even if I can provide rowkey ranges?

Comment: only if the rowkey spans an increasing number of rows. The row keys help limit the number of entities in the partition that will be scanned for any other matching criteria. As long as you limit the number of entities/rows, you should still be fairly performant.